# Vue nuxt.config.js file ignored

Tags: vue.js, proxy, axios, nuxt.js

So i have the `nuxt.config.js` file in the project root directory with what follows:

```
{
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/proxy'
  ],
  axios: {
    proxy: true,
  },
  proxy: {
    'http://localhost:8080/api/v1': 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1'
  }
}
```

I've been struggling to understand why my calls were not proxed (the endpoint remains the same) and then i noticed that even if i break the syntax (removing commas or parenthesys or whatever) and restart the server, my app does not even care.

Can anyone help me make things work?

Answer (score 0):

#### @nuxtjs/proxy already included

`@nuxtjs/axios` already includes `@nuxtjs/proxy`, so you don't need to install it separately; and you don't need to add it to `modules` array:

```js
{
  modules: [
   '@nuxtjs/axios',
   //'@nuxtjs/proxy', // DON'T DO THIS
  ]
}
```

#### Proxy URL incorrect

Currently, you have it setup to append the original URL to the target, as shown in this example:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/v1/foo --> http://localhost:3000/api/v1/api/v1/foo
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The config should look like this:

```js
{
  proxy: {
    'http://localhost:8080/api/v1': 'http://localhost:3030'
  }
}
```

#### Be careful of duplicate `axios` configs

If you used [`create-nuxt-app`](https://github.com/nuxt/create-nuxt-app), `nuxt.config.js` already includes an empty `axios` config, which could be easily missed. If you inserted your own config at the top of the config object, it would be overwritten by the empty `axios` config that had been automatically inserted at the bottom of the object (which effectively disables the proxy):

```js
// nuxt.config.js
module.exports = {

  // your config
  axios: {
    proxy: true
  },


  //...


  // was automatically inserted; overwrites your config above
  axios: {}
}
```

Comment: I didn't use `create-nuxt-app`, i just launched `npm install @nuxtjs/axios --save` and then manually created the `nuxt.config.js` file. How do i enable axios to be proxied?

Also, if i intentionally make a syntax error in this file, the application does not raise any error.

Comment: `@nuxtjs/axios` enables proxying with `axios.proxy=true`, which you already configured. Do you have a GitHub link to a sample reproduction?

Comment: "nuxtjs/proxy already included" This seems to be true in my tests as I still have successful proxy-api/cors/remote-testing/etc after removing the proxy module and re-building. Nuxt's doc page mentions having both Axios and Proxy modules: https://nuxtjs.org/faq/http-proxy, maybe the doc needs updating?